# Unique local variables in Angular 2 For Loop

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a for loop that used to work until I started using JQuery UI's Datepicker on the date input. This plugin break the data-binding, so ngModel no longer updates its value. Here is my code:

```
<div *ngFor="let list of checklists">
    ...    
    <div *ngFor="let item of list.TaskItems">
        <form (ngSubmit)="addItem(list.Id, list.NewItemName, list.NewItemDetails, list.NewItemDate)" #addNewItemForm="ngForm">
            <!--Date-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input class="form-control task-date date-picker" id="Date" name="Date" type="datetime" [(ngModel)]="list.NewItemDate">                
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Cancel/Save-->
            <div class="row addCancel-row">
                <div class="addCancel">
                    <button type="submit" class="add-this-task save-button" [disabled]="!addNewItemForm.form.valid">Add this checklist item</button>
                    <button class="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Normally when I have this issue, I add a variable like `#date` to the input and add `date.value` as a parameter in the form submit method and it works just fine. Give that this time I am using a for loop, I get an error from having multiple variables with the same name. How can I create a unique local variable for each input in the for loop? I tried `#list.date`, but it didn't work.

Comment: rename it to another name?

Comment: One of us isn't understanding the other. I'm not manually naming all of the variables the same. It's inside a for loop. If there are 5 items in the loop, I will have 5 inputs that all have the same variable name and I'm trying to figure out a way to change that.